# All Office 365 programs go unresponsive after a short amount of time

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2016

I have installed Microsoft Office 365 ProPlus on Windows 10.  I had quite a bit of difficulty with this installation, the process would always fail with a 30015-11 error, though the program would show as installed in the Control Panel.  After doing a repair operation through control panel, Office "works"

What I mean is that all Office programs will work for a few minutes, and then go unresponsive.  Restarting them makes them work again, but this is not reasonable.

This version of office apparently relies on "Click to Run" architecture and there are multiple Office Click to Run processes running at all times (even when I have no office programs open)

How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a corrupt installation.  Try uninstalling and reinstalling and see if it resolves your issue.

If you have other versions of Microsoft Office installed, I would uninstall those first before reinstalling.  I've had trouble with having multiple installations of Microsoft Office on the same machine before.

Comment: I've done my best to uninstall previous versions of office.  In addition to a regular uninstall, I went through a manual uninstall guide to see what got left behind.  I've reinstalled a couple of times, but I'll keep trying it.